# My Node.js application through 'pg' module cannot make request/connection to the container running postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pg

Good morning,

I want my application running locally at my machine to connect to my PostgreSQL database running also locally in a container, so that I can perform CRUD operations. *However, the problem is that my application is failing to establish a connection to the PostgreSQL database running in the container.* **Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

**What is working so far:**

I have successfully set up my *Dockerfile* and *docker-compose.yml* file. Now, when I run 'npm run start,' it will create a container running the PostgreSQL image and perform the specifics migrations to create the desired tables. I can verify the container's status using the command:

```
docker ps
```

I can also interact with the postgres using the command:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> psql -U postgres
```

*So, here I see that the tables are beeing created correct, I can interact with it without any problems.*

**What is real the problem?**

The problem is that my Node.js application, running on my local machine, cannot make a request to the container. When it tries to fetch data from the PostgreSQL database, it throws an error:

[image]

**However, it is unable to make the request or, in other words, it cannot establish a connection to the PostgreSQL container.**

I am using the module pg to interact with the PostgreSQL.
**For a better overview, please, check my project at** [github project link](https://github.com/MKortmann/storefront-backend).

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**
Thank you very much!

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer. Your code looks fine to me. I suggest you try to connect to your postgres via a tool like pgAdmin, TablePlus or DataSpell from your local machine. Maybe there is more of a docker / postgres configuration problem than a javascript issue?

Comment: Thank you @Silvan! I will try to connect on it using the pgAdmin ... It is a great advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have to change the host and the port at .env because the pg module is running at my local machine trying to access the container port 5433 at localhost.
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5433